# .NET OleDBDataReader storing read queries

Tags: c#, .net, database, oledb

I am looking for the best practices in storing OleDBDataReader's reads. Essentially I want it to retain that same dictionary like reader["Column"]. I am writing an API that returns a data structure made up of "rows." I feel like there must be a better solution than creating an ArrayList of dictionaries but I cannot seem to find a "best practice" for this.

The code below is taken from my current project

```
using (var commandToQueryDB = new OleDbCommand(query))
{
     commandToQueryDB.Connection = Connection;
     Connection.Open();
     var reader = commandToQueryDB.ExecuteReader(); 
     while (reader.Read())
     {
          //Insert reader's read in some sort of data structure
     }
}
```

I would like to be able to iterate through the queries and then access each query as a dictionary (e.g query["DistrictName"] if I had a table with DistrictName as a column)

Comment: First, this probably should be moved to codereview since it works. Second, why not just put your data into an object and then store it in a list. You can then use linq filtering to get whatever you want

Comment: Because this API is used for DB's in which the Schema might not be known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reader is a "pipe", not a "bucket" - the reader API is not suitable for disconnected data. For that, it depends on whether you know the schema of the data.

If you do know the schema at compile-time, then *populate a typed class model* - just a `List<Foo>` will do nicely. There are tools that can make this even simpler, handling the member population for you, etc; "dapper" leaps to mind (although I am biased).

If you do *not* know the schema in advance, then `DataTable` may be suitable. I don't usually recommend it, but it does the job here. Just:

```
table.Load(reader);
```

is enough to populate a `DataTable` including schema (columns) and values (rows / cells).

Comment: What are the weaknesses of Datatable? Why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: @Alexander if you know the schema, using a simple object model has much fewer overheads. DataTable adds complexity, abstraction, and flexibility and features that you *probably don't need*. If this isn't a performance critical area, you'll probably get away with it. Additionally, though, note that a DataTable is inherently not well typed - the compiler and and IDE will not be able to help you get this right.

Comment: @Alexander There is such a thing as "typed datasets / datatables", but for the love of all that is decent in this world don't go there - that is bad things pretending to be good. If a typed datatable is an option, then a regular poco would be a better choice.

Comment: @Alex and to be clear - I do use datatable occasionally - but only when the schema cannot be known at compile-time

Comment: Well, the issue is that this API is a "base" (abstract) DB driver and has no information about the schema. My idea was to allow other developers to inherit from this base class to implement easy to use drivers for DB's with compile-time known schemas. So I guess in a way this is not exactly an API, but APIs will be built on top of this for specific DBs.

Comment: @Alexander well, that is one way of solving the problem; the other is to get the caller to *tell you* what they want - look at tools like "dapper", for example - that also has no knowledge of the caller's model, but that doesn't prevent it from working with it

Comment: Would you recommend loading the entire DB as a DataTable and then run the queries on it? Can LINQ style queries be run on a DataTable?